# How does Ruby's for loop work, (compared to Python)?

Tags: python, ruby, loops

I am currently jumping onto the Ruby train and I have some basic Python knowledge, which I hoped would help me, however I am not clear as to how Ruby's 'for' loops work and my feeling is that they work differently when compared to Python.

An example could be the following python code:

```
print('Interest Calculator: ')
sumnum = eval(input('Enter your initial sum: '))
initnum = sumnum
rate = eval(input('Enter your interest rate: '))
noy = eval(input('Enter the number of years to calculate      your interest for: '))
for i in range(noy):
    sumnum = initnum * (1 + rate)

print('The value of your initial investment of £%s' %initnum, 'over the course of', noy, 'years is £%s' %sumnum)
```

Which produces the following (I put random numbers in):

```
Interest Calculator: 
Enter your initial sum: 250
Enter your interest rate: 3
Enter the number of years to calculate your interest for: 7
The value of your initial investment of £250 over the course of 7 years is £1000
```

What would a Ruby equivalent of the for loop here be?

I tried to do it like so:

```
puts 'Interest Calculator: '
puts 'Enter your initial sum: '
sumnum = gets
initsum = sumnum
puts 'Enter your interest rate: '
rate = gets
puts 'Enter number of years for your interest: '
noy = gets
for i in noy do
 sumnum = initsum * (1 + rate)
end

puts "The value of your investment of £#{initsum} over the course of #{noy} years is £#{sumnum}"
```

This however, produces the following error:

```
Interest Calculator:
Enter your initial sum: 
250
Enter your interest rate: 
3
Enter number of years for your interest: 
7
~/RubymineProjects/ExploreRuby/InterestRate.rb:9:in `<top   (required)>': undefined method `each' for "7\n":String  (NoMethodError)
from -e:1:in `load'
from -e:1:in `<main>'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change:

```
for i in noy do
 sumnum = initsum * (1 + rate)
end
```

to:

```
noy.to_i.times do
 sumnum = initsum.to_i * (1 + rate)
end
```

if you insist on using the `for` loop then:

```
for i in (1..noy.to_i) do
  sumnum = initsum.to_i * (1 + rate)
end
```

The `for` loop in ruby is a wrapper around `each` so the object you intend to iterate on must respond to `each`, `noy` in this case is a string an not an `Enumerable` object

Answer (score 0):

Using 'for' in Ruby is typically written using 'each', this is the more idiomatic way. 
If you care to read more about 'for vs each' you can [right here](http://web.archive.org/web/20120711111451/http://blog.grayproductions.net/articles/the_evils_of_the_for_loop).

A one-line liner (eliminating the 'do' that opens your block) could be:

```
noy.to_i.times { sumnum = initsum.to_i * (1 + rate) }
end
```

Comment: That's handy. Thanks!